# Service and version displayed via nmap scan for simple python socket server

Tags: python, sockets, banner, nmap

I've got a simple python socket server. Here's the code:

```
import socket
host = "0.0.0.0" # address to bind on.
port = 8081

def listen_serv():
    try:
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        s.bind((host,port))
        s.listen(4)

...
messages back and forth between the server and client
...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    while True:
        listen_serv()
```

When I run the python server locally and then scan with `nmap localhost` i see the open port 8081 with the service blackice-icecap running on it. A quick google search revealed that this is a firewall service that uses the port 8081 for a service called ice-cap remote. If I change the port to 12000 for example, I get another service called cce4x.

A further scan with `nmap localhost -sV` returns the contents of the python script

```
1 service unrecognized despite returning data. If you know the service/version,
please submit the following fingerprint at https://nmap.org/cgi-bin/submit.cgi?new-service :
SF-Port8081-TCP:V=7.25BETA1%I=7%D=8/18%Time=57B58EE7%P=x86_64-pc-linux-gn
SF:u%r(NULL,1A4,"\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\
SF:*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\n\*\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x
SF:20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\
SF:x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\*\n\*\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x
SF:20Welcome\x20to\x20ScapeX\x20Mail\x20Server\x20\x20\x20\x20\*\n\*\x20\x
SF:20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\
SF:x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20
SF:\x20\x20\*\n\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\
SF:*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\nHere\x20is\x20a\x20quiz\x20to\x20test\x20your\
SF:x20knowledge\x20of\x20hacking\.\.\.\n\n\nAnswer\x20correctly\x20and\x20
SF:we\x20will\x20reward\x20you\x20with\x20a\x20shell\x20:-\)\x20\nQuestion
    etc...
    etc...
```

Is there a way I can customize the service and version descriptions that are displayed by nmap for my simple python server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution by sending the following line as the first message from the server

```
c.send("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nServer: Netscape-Enterprise/6.1\r\nDate: Fri, 19 Aug 2016 10:28:43 GMT\r\nContent-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\nConnection: close\r\nVary: Accept-Encoding\n\nContent-Length: 32092\r\n\n\n""")
```